# Selectively apply custom function based on criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with this dataframe:

```
 structure(list(year = c("2012", "2016", "2012", "2016"), month = c("12", 
"12", "12", "12"), company = c("ALSN", "ALSN", "DAN", "DAN"), 
    Revenue = c(2141.8, 1840.2, 7224, 5826), `Cost of Goods Sold` = c(1187.5, 
    976, 6250, 4982), `Gross Profit` = c(954.3, 864.2, 974, 844
    ), `Gross Margin %` = c(44.56, 46.96, 13.48, 14.49), `Selling, General, & Admin. Expense` = c(419, 
    323.9, 424, 406), `Impairment Of Capital Assets` = c(0, 0, 
    2, 0), Advertising = c(1, 1, 1, 1), `Research & Development` = c(115.1, 
    88.8, 0, 0), `Restructuring And Mergern Acquisition` = c(0, 
    0, 47, 0), `Other Operating Expense` = c(-5.68434188608e-14, 
    1.13686837722e-13, 121, 8), `Operating Income` = c(420.2, 
    451.5, 429, 430), `Operating Margin %` = c(19.62, 24.54, 
    5.94, 7.38), `Interest Income` = c(0.9, 0.7, 24, 13), `Interest Expense` = c(-152.1, 
    -101.6, -84, -113), `Net Interest Income` = c(-151.2, -100.9, 
    -60, -100), `Other Income (Expense)` = c(-52.8, -9.3, -5, 
    -115), `Non Operating Income` = c(-52.8, -9.3, -5, -115), 
    `Other Income (Minority Interest)` = c(0, 0, -15, -13), `Gain on Sale of Security` = c(-1.3, 
    -0.8, 0, 7), `Write Off` = c(1, 1, 1, 1), `Pre-Tax Income` = c(216.2, 
    341.3, 364, 215), `Tax Provision` = c(298, -126.4, -51, 424
    ), `Tax Rate %` = c(-137.84, 37.03, 14.01, -197.21), `Net Income (Continuing Operations)` = c(514.2, 
    214.9, 315, 653), `Net Income (Discontinued Operations)` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0), `Net Income` = c(514.2, 214.9, 300, 640), `Net Margin %` = c(24.01, 
    11.68, 4.15, 10.99), `Preferred Dividends` = c(0, 0, 31, 
    0), `EPS (Basic)` = c(2.83, 1.28, 1.82, 4.38), `EPS (Diluted)` = c(2.76, 
    1.27, 1.4, 4.36), `Shares Outstanding (Diluted Average)` = c(186.2, 
    168.8, 214.7, 146.8), `Depreciation, Depletion and Amortization` = c(252.5, 
    175.9, 277, 182), EBITDA = c(620.8, 618.8, 725, 510)), .Names = c("year", 
"month", "company", "Revenue", "Cost of Goods Sold", "Gross Profit", 
"Gross Margin %", "Selling, General, & Admin. Expense", "Impairment Of Capital Assets", 
"Advertising", "Research & Development", "Restructuring And Mergern Acquisition", 
"Other Operating Expense", "Operating Income", "Operating Margin %", 
"Interest Income", "Interest Expense", "Net Interest Income", 
"Other Income (Expense)", "Non Operating Income", "Other Income (Minority Interest)", 
"Gain on Sale of Security", "Write Off", "Pre-Tax Income", "Tax Provision", 
"Tax Rate %", "Net Income (Continuing Operations)", "Net Income (Discontinued Operations)", 
"Net Income", "Net Margin %", "Preferred Dividends", "EPS (Basic)", 
"EPS (Diluted)", "Shares Outstanding (Diluted Average)", "Depreciation, Depletion and Amortization", 
"EBITDA"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Constants:**

```
startDate <- "2012-01-01"
endDate <- "2016-12-31"
```

**What I want:** to create a function that applies a custom function to all numeric columns. I am trying to calculate CAGRs. The CAGR formula is as such:

((End Value / Beginning Value)^(1/number of years)-1)

So as you can see, I need for each column to be able to find the correct end value and beginning value.

**My function right now is this:**

```
cagr <- function(startval,endval,x,y,years){
  return(((endval[x == year(endDate)]/startval[y == year(startDate)])^(1/(years-1)))-1)
}

cagrNew <- function(df,colum,x,y,years){
  colum <- quo(colum)
  x <- quo(x)
  y <- quo(y)
  out <- df %>%
    group_by(!!company) %>%
    summarise(xxxx = cagr(!!colum[!!x == year(endDate)],!!colum[!!y == year(startDate)],!!x,!!y,numYears))
  return(out)
}
```

**When I run the above function (cagrNEW), I get this error:**

```
Error in `[.formula`(colum, !(!x == year(endDate))) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

**My desired output:**

```
Company    RevenueCagr     Cost of Goods Sold CAGR ....
ALSN          .5%             .3%
DAN           .3%             .2%
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your problem. You reference columns 4:36, and there are only 4 columns provided. You haven't provided gross profit for DAN in the reproducible code. what are the start dates and end dates you want to be using? I'm struggling to understand your summarise statement and what you want out of it.

Comment: @MattW. I have updated the dataframe and added more info of what it is exactly I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't repeated the data above, to conserve space. Convert to  tibble and assign.

```
# df <- as_tibble(...)


library(tidyverse)
library(scales) #< For percentage formatting

start_year <- 2012
end_year <- 2016

df %>% 
  filter(year %in% c(start_year, end_year)) %>% 
  group_by(company) %>% 
  arrange(desc(year), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.double, funs(CAGR =  percent( (.[[1]]/.[[2]])^ (1/(end_year - start_year)) - 1) )  ) 
                      # CAGR = ((End Value / Beginning Value)^(1/number of years)-1)

#Checksum: ALSN Company, Revenue
# (End Value / Beginning Value)^((1/number of years))-1 
percent(( (1840      / 2142)           ^ (1/(2016-2012))    - 1))
#> [1] "-3.73%"
```

Comment: This look right, except the CAGR is definitely not that high. I think you want to wrap the exponent in additional parentheses.

Comment: Parenthesis! Love them AND hate them.